# Change text after element

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have simple form with adding elements to db. I use the same form for editing. I need to change button text from `add item` to `edit item`. I have no idea how to edit only text after `span` without touch `span`.

```
<button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn btn-md pull-right btn-info">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add item
</button>
```

I want to have this:

```
<button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn btn-md pull-right btn-info">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> Edit item
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of struggling to select the specific piece of text - wrap it with a `label` and select it via jQuery. Much more elegant and readable.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better practice to just amend the HTML directly. Assuming you can't do that you would need to get the textNode of the `button` and amend it. Try this:

```
$('button').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.trim() != '';
}).get(0).nodeValue = 'Edit item';
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rcx8sbds/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lastChild` with `textContent`.

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/polareqisa/edit?html,js,output)

```
var txt = document.getElementById('form-submit').lastChild.textContent;
```

You can use childNodes to get particular child

```
var txt = document.getElementById('form-submit').childNodes[2].textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Getting the value**

```
$('#form-submit').text(); //gives you 'Add Item' before change
```

**Changing the value**

```
$('#form-submit').text("Edit Item"); //changes 'Add Item' to 'Edit Item'
```

You do not need to do anything complicated more than this to get and edit the value inside the button.

In this case you don't even have to touch the `span` element. It just extracts the pure text inside the `<button>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this its simple, one line and it may help.

```js
$('#form-submit:contains("Add item")').text('Edit Item');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn btn-md pull-right btn-info">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add item
</button>
```

Comment: Ok but... where now is my <span /> ? :> `edit only text after span without touch span.`

Comment: Use the below code which will not disturb html code

var str = document.getElementById("form-submit").innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace("Add item", "Edit item"); document.getElementById("form-submit").innerHTML = res;